# Add +1 to span and displaying am I doing this the hard way?

Tags: jquery

I have a feeling there is a much easier way to do this, but even this took me a bit to figure out. I need to remember that javascript and php are have similar syntax. Can someone reduce this?

I even tried `$('span#'+venue).html(thisvenuecount++);` but that didn't work.

```
var thisvenuecount = $('span#'+venue).html();
thisvenuecount++;
$('span#'+venue).html(thisvenuecount);
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="badge pull-right" id="69">1</span>
```

Comment: Im just trying to add +1 to the count. Its a number that I get from the value. This works but I feel likes it more than I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud parse it to an int first.

```
var venue = 69;
$('span#'+venue).html(parseInt($('span#'+venue).html()) + 1);
```

Or even:

```
var el = $('#69');
el.html(parseInt(el.html()) + 1);
```